# Converting category labels into binary in R

Tags: python, r

I am wondering if there is a built in command in R that would replicate the pd.get_dummies() function in python.

What this does is, for example I have a data set T

```
Chris     Male
Mary      Female
Bob       Male
John      Male
```

I want it to convert these unique categories (Male and Female) into binary data, such as having it show as

```
         Male     Female
Chris     1          0
Mary      0          1
Bob       1          0
John      1          0
```

Would anyone be able to shine some light on this? I would like to know the function and package that would need to be applied. If there does not exist one, how would you convert it?

Comment: `table(df)` should do it.

Comment: table(df) seems to only sum up all the males: 3 and females: 1

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out.

```
model.matrix(~dataset)
```

works just fine.